# run the query in Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

how this query use in Codeigniter

```
`SELECT `messages`.`id`, left(`messages`.`message`, 150) 
     as 'message', `messages`.`message_group_id`, `messages`.`date_added` 
 FROM (`messages`) WHERE `message_group_id` = '".$messageGroupID."' 
 ORDER BY `messages`.`id` desc LIMIT 1`
```

Comment: The codeigniter manual can help you here. Have you attempted to solve your problem? What didn't work? What did you try?

Comment: You can try it with active records. http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = $this->db->query('YOUR QUERY HERE');
```

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$this->db->select('messages.id, left(messages.message, 150) as message, messages.message_group_id, messages.date_added', false)->where('message_group_id', $messageGroupID)->order_by('messages.id', 'desc')->get('messages', 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

$query = $this->db->get('mytable', 10, 20);

// Produces: SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT 20, 10 (in MySQL. Other databases have slightly different syntax)

For more refer: **[LINK](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select)**